# How to italicize words in a cell that follow a hyphen

Tags: excel, vba, delimiter, bold, italics

appreciate you reading this post. I'm sure this is a simple one, but I'm new to VBA coding.

I've got a list of words between cell D23:D52 in a spreadsheet that are all separated by a hyphen. IE: "word1 word2 - word3 word4" I'd like to format the words to the left of the hyphen as BOLD and the words to the right of the hyphen as ITALICS like this: "**word1 word2 -** *word3 word4*"

I can only figure out how to either italicize every word or make every word bold. I figure there has to be a way to split the words into italics and bold using the hyphen as a delimiter.

Is there a code that would help me achieve this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: You might get partway there by recording a macro while applying the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
     Dim c As Range, aTxt
     For Each c In Range("D23:D52")
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If InStr(c.Value, "-") > 0 Then
                aTxt = Split(c.Value, "-")
                c.Characters(1, Len(aTxt(0))).Font.Bold = True
                c.Characters(Len(aTxt(0)) + 2, Len(aTxt(1))).Font.Italic = True
            End If
        End If
     Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Characters property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144092)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008907)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)